R Gmean calculation of confidence interval
I am trying to calculate both geometric mean and the standard deviation of a short vector (5-9 data points) using Gmean{DescTools} and Gsd. Both functions work, but I am having difficulty "checking" the two-sided 95% confidence interval calculated by Gmean by using the geometric mean and its standard deviation from Gsd.
How is the "conf.level=0.95" in Gmean calculated?
(edits added after Friede)
The MeanCI src for the "classic" method uses:
a <- qnorm(p = (1 - conf.level)/2) * sd/sqrt(length(x))
instead of the qt() method I mention above.
If we assume a dataset of rnorm(50, mean = 20, sd = 5)
Gmean with conf.level 0.95 yields:
mean   lwr.ci   upr.ci
17.96132 16.32157 19.76580
(I know we expect a mean of 20, but since my data are ratios I need to use geometric mean).
Gsd(x) gives a value of 1.400535, calculated as exp(SD(log(x)))
Using the code for MeanCI described above using qnorm, I get a value of
qnorm(p = (1-0.95)/2) * 1.400535 / sqrt(50) = -0.3882012
How does Gmean calculate the 95% CI intervals from that?
17.96132 - 0.3882012 does not yield 16.32157

Gmean has else exp(MeanCI(x = log(x), method = method, conf.level = conf.level,  sides = sides, ...)), i.e. look at the source code of MeanCI: https://github.com/AndriSignorell/DescTools/blob/master/R/MeanCI.R
